how to get source code of a ruby proc/lambda
e.g. i'm trying to do this:
Benchmark.ips(-> { add }, -> { sub })

currently i'm doing:
def Benchmark.ips(*reports, &block)
  if reports.any?
    super() do |x|
      reports.each do |report|
        x.report(report.to_s) { report.call }
      end
    end
  else
    super
  end
end

but that doesn't really work:
#<Proc:0x0000000102d0d3f8 a.rb:61 (lambda)>
                         1.810M i/100ms

I would like to display "add" and "sub" where there is report.to_s
(this is a very early version of an idea)
(see my comments for why the existing answers don't answer the question)

the answers don't work when the procs are on the same line

also the answers are from 8+ years ago, ruby has changed a lot since

i think i'm just gonna print the index basically, should be enough

Given your basic example you could just go with a ["add","sub"].each {|report| x.report(report) { public_send(report)} } or x.report(report, &method(report))

Printing the proc's source code might be useful for single method call or a (very) short expression but what about procs spanning multiple lines – wouldn't that mess the report's output? Why not add explicit labels, e.g. Benchmark.ips(add: -> { add }, sub: -> { sub })
